# MSI Wind U123 Touchpad only work if LAN connected and Active

Tags: ethernet, touchpad, netbook

I have a MSI Wind U123 Netbook ... all of a sudden lately, the touch-pad refuses to work correctly unless the LAN cable is **connected and active**. If i unplug the LAN cable, I can't control the mouse pointer and it starts running fast and jumping; it even clicks on its own sometimes.

My only options now are to use a USB mouse or to keep LAN connected and active everywhere I go (which is not available all the time).

I don't know what happened to it. Where should I start? Any help is really appreciated.

PS: **It is hardware related**, I've tried Windows XP, Windows 7, and a few Linux distributions and it's the same touch-pad problems in all of these OS's.

Comment: Sounds, _to me_, like defective hardware. How long have you had the netbook? When did it start? What is the warranty?

Comment: @Raystafarian I've had it almost 2 years now, the problems started about 4 months or so, and the warranty was for just one year (battery 6 months).